# Как добавить сайдбар вместе с оберткой для списка продуктов?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Куда нужно добавить сайдбар что бы на странице магазина и категорий он появлялся на одном уровне с товарами?

Я нашел вывод списка товаров в файлах цикла loop-start.php и loop-end.php добавил вывод сайдбара и моей обертки , но вот проблема теперь состоит в том что при изменении фильтра с аяксом он начинает циклить сайдбар, где еще его можно вывести или как пофиксить?

[Проект](http://jetdestw.bget.ru/product-category/wrist-watch/)

вывод который я использую в файле loop-start

```
<?php if( is_product_category() ){
  echo'<div class="product-category-wrap">';
  get_sidebar();
  echo '<div class="product-category__items">';
} ?>

<?php if( is_shop() ){
  echo'<div class="product-category-wrap">';
  get_sidebar();
  echo '<div class="product-category__items">';
} ?>
```

```html
<div class='product-category-wrap'>
  <aside></aside>
  <ul class='product'>
    <li class='item'></li>
   </ul>
  </div
```

Comment: Набросайте схему, а то как-то тяжело воспринимается, что и куда вывести, у вас в магазине уже есть сайдбар с фильтром. Куда его нужно закинуть? Над фильтром слева или справа? Не понятно

Comment: @eugene_v http://jetdestw.bget.ru/product-category/wrist-watch/
структура фильтра здесь такая .product-category-wrap>aside+ul.product

Comment: да я видел структуру, вы в paint набросайте расположение блоков, это сюда и стрелка, вот это сюда и т.д.

Comment: @eugene_v Ну надеюсь так более понятно про расположение https://yadi.sk/i/GIvlLF7V32bPVo

Мне по идее нужно изменить место вывода сайдбра и обертки для страницы категории, т.к вывод сейчас стиот в цикле и при изменении фильтра сайдбар уходит в цикл и дублируется по 4 раза